# Retrieving Navigation Properties with NHibernate Criteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

I think I'm just searching for the wrong terms, since I can't seem to find an answer to what I'm fairly sure is a simple question.

I have two classes/mappings (simplified);

```
public class Applications
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ApplicationType {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationProperty> ApplicationProperties {get; set;}
}

public class ApplicationProperties
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Application_Id {get; set}
    public string Value {get; set;}
}
```

I'm trying to build up a Criteria class in a (possibly misguided) attempt to make our code more readable/reusable, as follows;

```
public static class ApplicationsQuery
{
    public static ICriteria GetQuery(ISession session)
    {
        return session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Application));
    }

    public static ICriteria WithType(this ICriteria crit, ApplicationType type)
    {
        crit.Add(
            Restrictions.Eq(
                Projections.ProjectionList().Add(
                    Projections.Property<Application>(a => a.ApplicationType)), type));
        return crit;
    }

    public static ICriteria WithProperties(this ICriteria crit)
    {
        // What goes here?!
    }
}
```

So that I can do something like

```
ICriteria query = ApplicationsQuery.GetQuery(session).WithType(ApplicationType.GameServer).WithProperties();
```

I've tried various things such as;

```
 DetachedCriteria properties =
            DetachedCriteria.For<Application>()
                .SetProjection(Projections.Property<Application>(a => a.ApplicationProperties));
 return crit.Add(Subqueries.Select(properties));
 // Or this
 return crit.SetFetchMode("ApplicationProperties", FetchMode.Eager);
```

But I'm unable to get the ApplicationProperties to be populated.
My test setup looks like this;

```
session.Save(new Application("Test Application 1", ApplicationType.GameServer), 1);
session.Save(new Application("Test Application 2", ApplicationType.Manager), , 2);
session.Save(new ApplicationProperty(1, "Test Property"), 1);
```

**EDIT**
Adding in the mappings as I get the feeling that there *might* be an issue with them.

```
public class ApplicationMapping : ClassMap<Application>
{
    public ApplicationMapping()
    {
        Table("Applications");
        Id(o => o.Id, "Application_Id").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(o => o.Name).Column("Logical_Name");
        Map(o => o.ApplicationType).Column("Application_Type").CustomType<ApplicationType>();

        HasMany(o => o.ApplicationProperties).KeyColumn("Application_Id").ReadOnly().Cascase.None();
    }
}

public class ApplicationPropertyMapping : ClassMap<ApplicationProperty>
{
    public ApplicationPropertyMapping()
    {
        Table("Application_Properties");
        Id(o => o.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("Property_Id");
        Map(o => o.ApplicationId).Column("Application_Id");
        Map(o => o.Value).Column("Property_Value");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: i stripped down the code

```
public class ApplicationsQueryBuilder
{
    private static readonly IProjection ApplicationTypeProperty = Projections.Property<Application>(a => a.ApplicationType);

    private readonly DetachedCriteria _query = DetachedCriteria.For<Application>();
    private bool _withProperties;
    private bool _filteredByCollection;

    public ApplicationsQueryBuilder WithType(ApplicationType type)
    {
        _query.Add(Restrictions.Eq(ApplicationTypeProperty, type));
        return this;
    }

    public ApplicationsQueryBuilder WithTypes(params ApplicationType[] types)
    {
        var or = Restrictions.Disjunction();
        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            or.Add(Restrictions.Eq(ApplicationTypeProperty, type));
        }

        _query.Add(or);
        return this;
    }

    public ApplicationsQueryBuilder WithProperties()
    {
        _withProperties = true;
        return this;
    }

    public ApplicationsQueryBuilder WithProperty(string name)
    {
        _query.CreateCriteria("ApplicationProperties")
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Name", name));
        _filteredByCollection = true;
        return this;
    }
    ...

    public ICriteria Create(ISession session)
    {
        if (_withProperties && _filteredByCollection)
        {
            _query.SetProjection(Projections.Id());
            return session.CreateCriteria<Application>()
                .SetFetchMode("ApplicationProperties", FetchMode.Eager);
                .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", _query));
        }
        else if (_withProperties)
        {
            return _query.GetExecutableCriteria(_session)
                .SetFetchMode("ApplicationProperties", FetchMode.Eager);
        }
        else
        {
            return _query.GetExecutableCriteria(session);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this `public IEnumerable<string> ApplicationProperties {get; private set;}` is valid. `ApplicationProperties` is a reference/navigation property and it should be the entire object, not just a string.

Comment: Do you really need a whole object? it looks like a simple string to me and NHibernate supports that. Tell me if you need help mapping it

Comment: Yeah, I simplified it somewhat. It's technically 4 strings; a `Name`, `Value`, `ExtendedValue1` and `ExtendedValue2` (all strings). I've got the mapping down fine and I can create a query to pull in `ApplicationProperties`, the problem is trying to pull in an `Application` along with all of it's `ApplicationProperties`.

Comment: Updated question with the mappings. I have a feeling they might be a problem after all.

Comment: You use Application and ApplicationProperty as data like in tables and not as Objects. I think what is happening here is that you save them individually and the sessions cache them in their original unconnected state. `session.Flush(); session.Clear()` after the `session.Save()` should work. I suggest to change ApplicationProperty to a dependent type instead an Entity with its own Id. I can post the mapping if needed.

Comment: Correct, they are entries in a database, hence the mappings. Application does have it's own Id; `Property_Id`. It is an identity field in the database. I actually trimmed back the mappings and found the `ReadOnly()` to be the issue.